# Start search activity with query in android

Tags: android, android-search

I am able to create `SearchActivity` in android. It works great but I want to show the `Query` in the `Search Widget` when the `SearchActivity` starts. How can I get this?
This is my `MainActivity` with search query `plumber`
[image]

This is my `SearchActivity` when I click search button
[image]

Now what I want is, when `SearchActivity` is opened it should have `plumber` in it's `Search.Widget` like in the `MainActivity` while entering query.

Comment: are you using SearchView compact?

Comment: just show an image what you want.. i will help you

Comment: @sector11 yes I am using `SearchView`. I followed http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/search/setup.html, this tutorial to make the `SearchView`.

Comment: @AvinashAjayPandey I have added image :)